# Internal Server Error WampServer with Rewrite Module is Active

Tags: .htaccess, localhost, wampserver

I wanna rewrite my URL I created the .htaccess file

```
# Turn Rewrite Engine on
Rewrite Engine on

# Rewrite for charts.php
RewriteRule ^test charts.php [NC,L]
```

And I activated rewrite_module in my apache modules, but without any result ?

Is there any solution ?

Comment: And what does your error log say about the error?

Comment: `RewriteEngine on`  not `Rewrite Engine on`...

Comment: Title should be `Internal Server Error WampServer with incorrect rewite code`

Comment: @arcee123 It's Work thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Apache, spelling can kill you.  I have more lives than cats because of how many times I was killed by linux spelling.

You are looking for `RewriteEngine on`.  `Rewrite Engine on` will not work.

Thanks.